# Cant use plug in using macro elixir

Tags: elixir, metaprogramming, phoenix-framework

So phoenix there are a few plugs I would like to put into a mixed in base_controller.ex but i.e.

`plug :xxx when action in [:xxx]`

However when I add this to a `__using__` macro action seems to be undefined i.e.

```
defmacro __using__(opts) do
  quote do
    use XXX.Web, :controller
    plug :xxx when action in [:xxx]
  end
end
```

Results in:

`unknown variable action or cannot invoke local action/0 inside guard`

Seems like action comes from `use XXX.Web, :controller` so I am unsure why it is undefined. Any ideas here?

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message could be better, but this seems to be due to Macro hygiene, which is renaming `action` before sending it to the `plug` macro. We can disable hygiene on the variable `action` using `Kernel.var!/1`. The following works for me:

```
quote do
  use XXX.Web, :controller
  plug :xxx when var!(action) in [:xxx]
end
```